# Closures - differences between R and Javascript

Tags: javascript, r, closures

What is the specific difference between R and Javascript that means that in the following two, very similar, examples, I need the additional line in the R version to "fix" the value of the parameter to the first anonymous function?

Is it because R defers evaluation until it's forced (as I think Lisp does), but that Javascript evaluates as early as it can?  Or am I on the wrong lines here?

#### R version

```
test <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  test[[i]] <- (function(index) {
    index <- index # why does R need this line when Javascript doesn't
    return (function() {
      print (index)
    })
  })(i)
}
test[[5]]()
test[[10]]()
```

#### Javascript version

```
test = new Array()
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
  test[i] = (function(index) {
    return function() {
      alert(index)
    }
  })(i)
}
test[5]()
test[10]()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R uses lazy evaluation.  You don't need `index <- index`
You can use `force(index)`

---

In other words, the value of `index` does not get computed until the value is actually used. Thus if any changes occurred between the time you passed the argument and when you evaluated the argument, those changes will be reflected in the final output.

`force`, as its name implies, forces the evaluation of an object.

When you use `index <- index` you are at that moment creating a different object with the same name.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. Haven't come across `force` before.  Actually, from reading the documentation for `force`, it appears just `index` on its own would do the trick too (in retrospect, not the best chosen of variable names).

Comment: @SJC -- Correct, but using `force(index)` is more expressive and will make your code more readable.